# How to properly identify the integration bounds

Tags: calculus, statistics, expected-value, variance

suppose

$f(y_{1}, y_{2}) = \begin{cases} 1 & 0\leq y_{1}\leq 2, \, 0 \leq y_{2} \leq 1, \, 2y_{2} \leq y_{1} \\ 
 0 & otherwise
\end{cases}$

The goal is to find $Var(y_{1} - y_{2})$

Without using Covariance, I have decided to use the property of expectation, namely, $ Var\,(y_{1} - y_{2}) = E\,[(y_{1} - y_{2})^2] - (E\,[y_{1} - y_{2}])^2$

$E\,[y_{1} - y_{2}]= \int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{1} (y_{1}-y_{2})* 1 \,\,dy_{2}\,dy_{1} = 1$

$E\,[y_{1} - y_{2}]= \int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{1} (y_{1}-y_{2})^2* 1 \,\,dy_{2}\,dy_{1} = \frac{4}{3}$ but my calculation is not correct.

The correct one should be:

$E\,[y_{1} - y_{2}]= \int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{y_{1}}{2}} (y_{1}-y_{2})^2* 1 \,\,dy_{2}\,dy_{1} = \frac{7}{6}$

Why do the bounds differ from E[A] to E[A^2]? Could anyone provide me with some explanation, please?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y_2$ is bounded as well at $E(A)$:

$$ \int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{y_1}{2}} (y_1-y_2)\cdot 1 \ dy_2 \ dy_1 =1$$

So in both cases the upper bound for $y_2$ is $\frac{y_1}{2}$.

Comment: I see why I am confused. I was thinking of first finding out the marginal of y1 and y2, then calculating the expected value of each. Therefore, the bound changes because we are looking at the individual case. Thank you so much!